# Intersection of optional type aliases

Tags: typescript, generics, types, interface, intersection

Quick summary of the problem:
I would like to have a generic type alias that offers type safety for developers while creating some functions. It should luck something like this:

```js
//Types for A and B are optional
//I left the empty object to indicate that these generic types are optional. I know that they do not work.
interface Handler<A = {}, B = {}> {
    func: (input: A & B) => void;
}

//Working example with object destructuring
const foo: Handler<{bar: string}> = {
    func: ({bar}) => console.log(bar)
}

//Type error
const foo: Handler<{bar: string}> = {
    //rar not available 
    func: ({rar}) => console.log(rar)
}
```

The biggest problem here that this does not work with the empty object I used above nor does it work with the `Record<string, unknown>` default because both versions allow all keys.

My current workaround is as follows:

```js
type PseudoEmpty = {_:0}
interface Handler<A = PseudoEmpty, B = PseudoEmpty> {
    func: (input: Omit<A & B, "_">) => void;
}
```

Which feels somewhat sketchy and more like I am missing the big picture behind conditional types to write the correct "empty type alias" myself.
Furthermore the generated error message is `Property '...' does not exist on type 'Pick '.` which offers no great feedback (however my IDE auto completion feature looks good with this setup)

So to end with a question:
Is there a type that actual evaluates to a "no keys"-object which I could use for my generic type default?

Thank you in advance

Edit: Somewhat my hello message is getting deleted when I edit this message, so please, even tho this is the end of my post, feel greeted!

Comment: You have a typo in your second `foo` function. You should use `bar` instead of `rar`

Comment: Also, I dont understand why it does not work with empty object? COuld you please provide more examples?

Comment: Okay, I does actually work with empty objects in the example I provided above. There might have been some other issue with the generic type system I used (the actual setup was more complex than this). Thanks for the help regardless!

Answer (score 0):

The example provided above actually works. I might have made some other type errors along the way. The actual code I used had a generic type system that what a bit more complicated.

```js
//This
interface Handler<A = {}, B = {}> {
    func: (input: A & B) => void;
}

//generates the expected type error here
const foo: Handler<{bar: string}, {abc: number}> = {
    //when accesing a property that is not available in the intersection
    func: ({bar, def}) => console.log(def)
}
```